# Is conversion of L-glutamate to 6-phospho-D-gluconate a feasible reaction?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I want to know whether a reaction is feasible or not. Can L-Glutamate ($\ce{C5H9NO4}$) be converted to 6-Phospho-D-gluconate ($\ce{C6H13O10P}$) or vice versa in one step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the structures of the two molecules you're interested in (below). There are many chemical changes required if one were to *theoretically* carry out the transformation.

In a synthetic sense this would require a very long sequence- a quick glance on SciFinder doesn't reveal anyone having done this (probably because it would be incredibly lengthy and has no real purpose).

Even biochemically, where the cells have highly specialised enzymes capable of effecting all manor of changes, I find it unlikely that the transformation can be achieved by a single enzyme acting upon the glutamate, and indeed a cursory flick through the biochemical pathways atlas shows no direct transformation between these two molecules.

> **Structure of L-Glutamate**
>
> [image]
>
> **Structure of 6-phospho-D-gluconate**
>
> [image]

Comment: ... and the conversion would probably not be stereo-specific enough.